# Compile and create a runnable jar file like eclipse, via cli

Tags: java, linux, buildbot

I would like to create a runnable jar in the same manner in which eclipse does, but from CLI. I am using buildbot and I would like to be able to automatically create, for example, nightly builds automatically, but are also runnable.

My Makefile:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JAR = jar
JARFLAGS = cfe ./bin/java.jar alone.Gameloop -C resources . -C ./
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $(wildcard alone/*.java)
    #$(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
    $(wildcard alone/*.java) \
#   alone/Enter.java \
#   alone/GameLoop.java \
#   alone/ImageRender.java \
#   Blah.java \
#   Library.java \
#   Main.java 

all: classes

default: classes

packages: jars

jars:
    #echo $(JAR) $(JARFLAGS) $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
    #false
    $(JAR) $(JARFLAGS) $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: What errors do you get from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stuff looks okay all you have to do is add $(CLASSES) to the jars target as a dependency:

jars: classes
    $(JAR) $(JARFLAGS) $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

and then `make jars` will do the stuff nightly